# How to get the number of vector elements inside a vector layer in open layers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Does anybody know how to get a count for the number of features present in an OL3 vector layer?

My vector layer is defined as follows, I'd like to know how many elements it has, and ideally how many are currently being rendered:

```
var styleCache = {};
var WFS_layer_Traffic_Lights = new ol.layer.Vector({
source : new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    projection : 'EPSG:3857',
    url : "Vector_Data/Traffic_Lights_Bordeaux.geojson"
}),


style : function(feature, resolution) {

    var path;
    var x_anchor;
    var y_anchor;       

    if(resolution < 4){
    path = 'Icons/Traffic_Lights_Sign_Icon_Small.png';
    x_anchor = 23;
    y_anchor = 90;
    }
    if(resolution >= 4 && resolution < 10){
    path = 'Icons/Traffic_Lights_Sign_Small.png'; 
    x_anchor = 16;
    y_anchor = 16;
    }       
    if(resolution >= 10){
    path = 'Icons/Traffic_Lights_Sign_Tiny.png';        
    x_anchor = 10;
    y_anchor = 10;
    }


    if (!styleCache[path]) {
        styleCache[path] = [new ol.style.Style({
            fill : new ol.style.Fill({
                color : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
            }),
            stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
                color : '#319FD3',
                width : 1
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    anchor: [x_anchor, y_anchor],
                    anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    src: path
                })),
            text : new ol.style.Text({
                font : '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                text : "",
                fill : new ol.style.Fill({
                    color : '#000'
                }),
                stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color : '#fff',
                    width : 4
                })
            }),
            zIndex : 1
        })];
    }
    return styleCache[path];
}
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the (GeoJSON) features are loaded you can call `getFeatures` on the vector source to get an array with references to the features included in the vector source. So, to get the number of features you can use the following:

```js
var featureCount = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length;
```

As stated above the source should be loaded for this to work. If you pass a `url` option to the source constructor the source will use an Ajax request to download features. This occurs asynchronously, meaning that the source won't contain features after construction.

You can register a `change` listener on the vector source to know when it's loaded:

```js
var vectorSource = vectorLayer.getSource();
var listenerKey = vectorSource.on('change', function(e) {
  if (vectorSource.getState() == 'ready') {
    var featureCount = vectorSource.getFeatures().length;
    // ...
    ol.Observable.unByKey(listenerKey);
    // use vectorSource.unByKey(listenerKey) instead
    // if you do use the "master" branch of ol3
  }
});
```

EDIT: I edited this to change from `change:state` to `change` as the event name.

Comment: Thank you, you've answered two questions in one for me as well, because I was wondering how I was going to deal with the asynchronous nature of the Ajax request thread once I was told how to get the number of features.  Such a great answer  Though I was wondering...

Comment: As mentioned in the last part of the question, I was wondering @erilem whether I can get the number of elements rendered as well??   Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `view.calculateExtent(map.getSize)` to get the current view extent and `vectorSource.getFeaturesInExtent` to get the features for that extent. But this not bulletproof, because it won't get you the correct result when the view is rotated, because of problem in `calculateExtent`, and because there maybe features that are outside the extent but still visible on the map (because they're represented with large symbols for example). So use this with caution.